# php can't respond json

Tags: php, angularjs, json, ajax

Why a php file does not respond as json, but it responds to the connected file.

**file respond**

```
 <?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
 include '../connect.php';
 mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");
 $sql="SELECT confer_name, confer_begin_time, confer_end_time, confer_value, con_img FROM conference";
 $outp = "";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
   while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
     if($outp != ""){$outp .=",";}
     $outp .='{"cname":"' .$rs["confer_name"]. '",';
     $outp .='"cbt":"' .$rs["confer_begin_time"] . '",';
     $outp .='"cet":"' .$rs["confer_end_time"] . '",';
     $outp .='"cvalue":"' .$rs["confer_value"] . '",';
     $outp .='"cimg":"' .$rs["con_img"] . '"}';
   }
   $outp = '{"records":['.$outp.']}';
   echo  $outp;
 }
 ?>//***
```

**file connect** This file is used to connect.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "----";
$password = "----";
$database = "----";

$conn = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$database);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

[This result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHSl4.png)

Comment: Suggest you use `json_encode()` rather than trying to build JSONStrings manually

Comment: **Remove the `echo "Connected successfully";` in your connect file**. That is going to be the first thing your js code will see and it wont make any sense. Notice thats what your result is showing you !!!

Comment: this is wrong too.  ?>//*** maybe //*** will be displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modify your code as below

```
$outp = json_encode($outp);
```

Comment: This is a "code only" answer.  Please write out a fuller explanation of why it works and the cause of the error.